# Function works only when launched manually (not when triggered) in Google Apps Script Form

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm doing a project in Google Apps Script and I must admit it is not a piece of cake for me as a beginner in this technology.

Here's my issue:
I would like to run a modal after my form has been submitted. It works but I found two issues connected to it.
1) It is only working when launched manually from google apps script window, the same function is not working when a trigger is connected to it, for some reason it doesn't run modal (even though it fires logger.log inside it, strange...)
2) Even if fired manually it shows not in the preview mode but in the edit mode which is quite surprising.

Thank you for any help!

Here's my chunk of code:

```
function openDialog() {
  Logger.log('testFunction') //to test if a trigger runs a function, I'm getting this logger properly
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
  FormApp.getUi() 
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}
```

Comment: Set the error notification of the trigger to "immediately" and check your mail to see what error message it is sending.

Comment: @Sergeinsas or simply go to the Stackdriver logs. @OP, replace `Logger.log` with `console.log` and then **View -> Stackdriver Logging**

Comment: It says that I can't run function FormApp.getUi() from this context

Comment: FormApp.getUi provides a handle only to the editing resource, as stated in the documentation: ["A script can only interact with the UI for the current instance of an open form editor (not the view that a respondent sees), and only if the script is bound to the form."](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#getUi()). So, I'm not sure why you expected the documentation to be wrong

Comment: and that's the answer... getUi works only when a user is at the keyboard, not on a formSubmit trigger.

Comment: @tehhowch : sorry, we were typing together ;D

Comment: Ok, I get it, the documentation of course says truth ;) But is there workaround to trigger modal after user submits?

Comment: nope ... Only user action can show a UI

Comment: Btw, why is like that? I think it would be much more helpful if the model would open in respondent view. In other word, why to need modal inside edit view? ;)